# how to capture the click event of a dynamically generated button in jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

i see there is this syntax for detecting any button click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(":button").click(function(event) {
                alert("Thanks for visiting!" + this.value);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

but what if i want to only detect a particular button on the page?

EDIT:  this seems fine for buttons that are setup at the beginning but in my case i am creating them dynamically with jquery.  it seems those buttons dont hit this code.  any ideas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to bind "click" to the jQuery "[live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)" function/event for that to work.  I would also recommend using either a special CSS class or id on the dynamically generated button.  Here is the description of the live even from jQuery.com.

> When you bind a "live" event it will
>   bind to all current and future
>   elements on the page (using event
>   delegation). For example if you bound
>   a live click to all "li" elements on
>   the page then added another li at a
>   later time - that click event would
>   continue to work for the new element
>   (this is not the case with bind which
>   must be re-bound on all new elements).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      //$(":button") would select all buttons
      //.className would work on an button with a CSS Class assignment of ClassName
      //Below shows how to do it on a specific ID
      $("#MyNewButtonID").live("click", function(event) {
         alert("Thanks for visiting!" + this.value);
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: As of 1.7 live is deprecated, later removed. http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.7/

Answer (score 0):

Give the input an ID or class then use `$(".class:button")` or `$("#id:button")`

Comment: In the former case, there might be more than one button with the class. In the latter case the :button is redundant as the ID uniquely identifies an element.

Comment: this only partially worked.  i updated the question to be more explicit

Answer (score 0):

use the correct selector to identify the buttons you want ( http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors )
then add click functionality.

$(":button") selects ALL buttons. You want to limit that to the specific set you need